# RTF field gets the replaced data after import

Tags: 2013, core-service, 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion

While importing a csv file to creata cms component using core service custom pages, there is an RTF field in schema and csv has value for this as:

```
<img src="tcm:32-97620" title="eCatalog_Product_Tag" alt="eCatalog_Product_Tag" style="width: 405px; height: 54px;/>
```

After component is created, editor see that the in above field value, "style" attribute is replace with "class" as follow:

```
<img src="tcm:32-97620" title="eCatalog_Product_Tag" alt="eCatalog_Product_Tag" class="c1"/>
```

Can anyone suggest here what could be the reason if we consider that the Core service Code is not explicitly doing it based on fieldType.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What happens when you paste it in a RTF directly? Seems weird indeed.

Comment: It does not give issue. It works.

Comment: I remember vaguely having problems in the past with the `<style>`_element_ in xhtml, I don't think it's valid inside `<body>`, but the attribute should work, especially if the CME lets you do it. Maybe you can try with a simpler core service app, focused just on this element? Something must be causing this.

Comment: Hmm....Thanks Nuno.

Also i am looking into XSLT filtering aspects as well. any suggestion around that?

Comment: I understand the XSLT filter "fires" as you click around or Save in the CME. Does it happen over Core Service as well? What I'm trying to figure out is where does that _specific_ class name come from--"c1." I might be wrong, but it doesn't seem like something Tridion would generate automatically.

Comment: Thanks Alvin! .I am sure tridion will not generate that automatically. and the "c1" even i am not sure how is it coming and that is for all component. in the page inspect element there are no such css class as well so that is more like and indication of replaced style attribute though it unclear to me.

Comment: Can you share the core service custom pages code you're using? Can you also confirm you've applied the default XSLT filter to the specific RTF of the schema you're using? And, finally, If you enter (into the source) of the same field the first <img> string and then hit the other two RTF tabs - when you return to the source tab what is the exact string then?

Comment: Thanks Dylan !

Code is pretty Big.. which part of it you want to look at. When i toggle between tabs in RTF it does not make any difference. As i said above even if i write/paste the <img .... > in rtf manually and sava/close comp, it stays there. this happens only after import using core service. Let me give one more try with code. I will update anything as soon as I get.

Comment: Ok so here is what i got.. "TidyNet.dll" is the once which is transforming the RTF contents and forcibly removes "style" attribute to create a css class like img.c1, img.c2 etc depending on style attribute occurrence in any HTML tag in custom page code itself. (sorry, realized it later !)So can anyone tell me if there is way to prevent it or a suitable and of course best practice kind of stuff to solve this problem.